# Using display data annotations in property grid c#

Tags: c#, winforms, data-annotations, propertygrid

I am creating a Windows Form Application in C# and using property grid in it. I am displaying properties of a Person class object in it and wanted to use Display data annotation to set property's description, display order of properties and other things. 
To implement the same I have added reference to **System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations** in my code and code for my Person class is like this:

```
class Person
    {
        [Display(Name = "First Name", Order = 1,
        Prompt = "Enter First Name", Description = "Person First Name")]
        public string firstname { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Last Name", Order = 2,
        Prompt = "Enter Last Name", Description = "Person Last Name")]
        public string lastname { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Age", Order = 3,
        Prompt = "Enter Age", Description = "Person Age")]
        public int age { get; set; }
    }
```

But data annotations not working. Here is screenshot of property grid in my app.. [screenshot of property grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bt3EG.jpg)

I am not able to understand why data annotation are not working in my code. Can anyone help out? Is there anything I am missing out? Do I need to implement any code segment to make them work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the property `PropertySort` of your propertyGrid to `PropertySort.NoSort`
and properties will be displayed in the order they are declared

```
propertyGrid1.PropertySort = PropertySort.NoSort;
```

Comment: Thanks. But why name and description parameters are not working in display attribute?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work if you use the attributes from System.ComponentModel namespace, for example:

```
[Description("This is the First Name")] 
[DisplayName("First Name")]       
public string firstname { get; set; }
```

Comment: But any suggestion or clue why Display annotation is not working? :/

Comment: not specifically sorry, have a read at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15051298/list-of-propertygrid-attributes

Comment: this is also a good link for you as it shows use of attributes https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22717/Using-PropertyGrid